# Port closes automatically when trying to connect

Tags: port, portforwarding

I have port fortforwarded both port 80 and 150 to try and connect to my wampserver/webpage.

When I check if the port is open on https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ or a software I use it says that the port is open. However when I try to connect the server/webpage I can not reach it.
If I check if the port is open while I am trying to connect/reach the website, it suddendly says that the port is closed.

Then if I stop the loading of the page/close the tab, and check if the port is open. It says that the port is open again.

I have an RT-N12D1 router.

My ISP also says the both ports should be able to be connected to/open

Comment: Does your router have a firewall enabled?. It may be blocking the connections on port 80 and 150

Comment: That did the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling the firewall in the routers settings stopped the port from closing automatically.